# Should not std::thread::id default constructor create a "NULL" id?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++11

The following code failed in my gcc version 4.8.0:

```
#include <thread>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    std::thread::id nobody;

    assert( nobody != std::this_thread::get_id() );
};
```

Is this behavior correct?

Comment: @Ali Maybe his libstdc++ is out of date?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Jonathan Wakely kindly looked at the issue an [he says (below in comments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064785/should-not-stdthreadid-default-constructor-create-a-null-id/16065305#comment23167697_16065305) that `-pthread` has to be passed to both the compiler and the linker. If I do that the code does not fail with gcc 4.7.2 either. So the answer has apparently nothing to do with the quoted e-mail. Thanks Jonathan!

---

<del>Here are some quotes straight form the gcc developer [Jonathan Wakely's mail](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2011-03/msg00068.html), written in 2011:</del>

> All the comparison operators on our std::thread::id rely on undefined
>   behaviour because our thread::id is just a pthread_t.
>
> [...]
>
> 2) operator== uses pthread_equal, which is undefined for invalid
>   thread IDs, POSIX says:
>
> ```
>    If either t1 or t2 are not valid thread IDs, the behavior is undefined.
> ```

<del>Although it was written two years ago, it probably still applies.

At the moment I cannot check the gcc codebase to say more.</del>

---

**Weird.** The following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main() {

    std::cout << "Started" << std::endl;

    std::thread::id nobody;

    if ( nobody != std::this_thread::get_id() )  {

      std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Finished" << std::endl;
}
```

produces:

```
Started 
OK 
Finished
```

Check [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8c7d29212213300d87e7326c3f8a4769-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba). However your code does fail with 4.7.2.

Comment: It only fails with 4.7.2 if you don't pass `-pthread` to the compiler and linker. Presumably `pthread_equal` always returns true when you don't link to `libpthread.so`, I guess that's a bug in `<thread>`, so I'd better fix it

Comment: To be clear, I don't think this is anything to do with the mail you quote, it's to do with trying to use `std::thread` and not linking with `-pthread`

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yes, now I get that, I update the answer right away.

Comment: This is now http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57060 -- but to get correct behaviour with GCC's `std::thread` you should always use `-pthread` anyway

Answer (score 6):

I don't have access to the C++11 standard but from the latest standard draft [n3485](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) [thread.thread.id]

> An object of type thread::id provides a unique identiﬁer for each thread of execution and a single distinct value for all thread objects that do not represent a thread of execution (30.3.1)

followed by

> id() noexcept;
>    Eﬀects: Constructs an object of type id.
>    Postconditions: The constructed object does not represent a thread of execution.

This seems to imply that what you are observing is a bug in gcc